# Check if Element content exist in XML file

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my XML file

```
<Customer>
  <PrivateCustomer>
    <Adresse>USA</Adresse>
    <Phone>12345678</Phone>
    <Name>Zaghi</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Sex>Man</Sex>
  </PrivateCustomer>
  <PrivateCustomer>
    <Adresse>USA</Adresse>
    <Phone>12345678</Phone>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>22</Age>
    <Sex>Woman</Sex>
  </PrivateCustomer>
</Customer>
```

I dont want to have duplicates Phone numbers. When i enter a phone number into a textbox i want it to check if the number already exist or no. If it exist there should come an error.

Here is a small part of my C# code:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
doc = XDocument.Load("PrivateCustomer.xml");

var NumberExist = doc.Descendants("PrivateCustomer").Where(x => !x.Elements("Phone").Any());


if (NumberExist != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Number already exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PrivateCustomer.xml");
var NumberExist = doc.Descendants("PrivateCustomer")
                .Any(x => (string)x.Element("Phone") == textBox1.Text);

if(NumberExist)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Number already exist");
}
```

If  all `PrivateCustomers` have at least one `Phone`,your query will always return *null*.Just use a *condition* with `Any` and check if there is a `PrivateCustomer` with a given phone number.